# Pythonanywhere don`t see a db dajngo

Tags: python, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I added virtualenv, pulled a project, created db(sqlite) from migrations. When i try to get info with postman I get a OperationalError at /auth/login no such table: client_api_profile. In bash I see, that this table exists, what i did wrong?[image]

Comment: This does not mean the table exists, it simply is the name that Django will try to use, based on how you configured your models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run migrations? What you access in bash is just a Model private attribute, not an actual database table. According to Django docs for Model Meta class:

**db_table**

Options.db_table -The name of the database table to use for the model:

```
db_table = 'your_custom_table_name'
```

Comment: Thx for advice, I added this, deleted DB, created new one with migration, still doesn`t work. 
Maybe it`s because pythonanywhere didn`t see a DB at all?

Comment: If you're using sqlite, make sure that the database file that you think your web app is using is actually the one that it is using: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NoSuchFileOrDirectory/